# How does Bullheading work?

Tags: fluid-dynamics, fluid-statics, geophysics

[image]Bullheading, a method of Well Kill, involves simply pumping the kill fluid (heavy fluid) directly down the well bore forcing the well bore fluids back into the reservoir, does the heavier fluid flip flop with the lighter fluid at the bottom? I don't understand why the heavy fluid doesn't flow into the reservoir and the lighter fluid move to the top.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Well_kill#Bullheading

Comment: The "reservoir" is actually a layer of porous rock, so the typical "heavy density sinks to the bottom" doesn't work.

Comment: @DavidWhite I would think the swapping of fluid would take place in the pipe that leads to the reservoir, not in the reservoir itself.

Comment: Mike, if the personnel running the drilling operation are continuously sending high density "mud" down the pipe, there will never be the chance for this "swapping of fluid" to take place.  They will send an excess of mud down the pipe, totally displacing the lower density drilling mud into the reservoir before stopping their operation.  In addition, the drilling muds are known to have physical properties that prevent "mixing"; otherwise, they would not be able to carry rock particles up the pipe to be disposed (i.e., the rock particles would settle back down the pipe as drilling commenced).

Comment: @DavidWhite As far as mixing goes, I don't know that prevention of mixing is a prerequisite for flip flopping because it is widely recognized that oil and water do not mix. However types of oil and water are also the standard fluids used to show this flip flopping mechanism throughout introductory courses. In fact, I would go further to say that the flip flopping occurs precisely because the two do not mix well. I accept the fact that there are 5000ft - 10000ft of pipe going down to the reservoir and because flip flopping is a function of time, it probably would never occur.

Comment: @DavidWhite It should also be noted that nowadays the pipe changes to a horizontal direction when entering the pay zone. This horizontal direction does not allow the vertical gravity/density effect to create significant fluid motion because the pipe is not aligned with the direction of the resultant force/motion.

Comment: They can pump down the fluid so fast, that not even bubbles of air manage to rise.